# Disable button if any of several inputs empty

Tags: html, typescript, ionic2

I'm wondering, how properly make disabled button if any of exist inputs empty in ionic2 application if Type Script:

```
  name: string = null;
```

this way in .html  useful for one input value to make button enabled or disabled:

```
<button ion-button (click)="add();" [disabled]="name === null" >Save</button>
```

from:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Name</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

but if I have several inputs:

```
  name: string = null;
  surname: string = null;
  username: string = null;
```

with fill of one input, button becomes enabled:

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Name</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Surname</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="surname"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Username</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
```

so it is incorrect:

```
 <button ion-button (click)="add();" [disabled]="name === null" [disabled]="surname === null" [disabled]="username === null" >Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy

```
<button [disabled]="!name || !surname || !username">Save</button>
```

If you have more complex logic you can use a property to keep the template clean.

```
get canSave() {
  return this.name && this.surname && this.username;
}
```

And reference it like so

```
<button [disabled]="!canSave">Save</button>
```

Note that I strongly advise against initializing your properties to `null`. A much better approach is simply to provide no initial value and annotate them meaningfully with `?` indicating that they may not have a value

```
name?: string;
surname?: string;
username?: string;
```

Comment: both ways are useful